# Permission denied on Cloud KMS key when using cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-kms

I am using `cloud storage` upload a file with kms key. Here is my code:

```js
await storage.bucket(config.bucket).upload(file, {
  kmsKeyName: `projects/${process.env.PROJECT_ID}/locations/global/keyRings/test/cryptoKeys/nodejs-gcp`,
  destination: 'mmczblsq.kms.encrypted.doc'
});
```

I have a `cloud-storage-admin.json` service account with `cloud storage admin` permission. Initialize the `storage` with this service account.

```js
const storage: Storage = new Storage({
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  keyFilename: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.gcp/cloud-storage-admin.json')
});
```

And, I use `gcloud kms keys add-iam-policy-binding` add `roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter` to `cloud-storage-admin.json` service account.

When I try to upload a file with kms key, still got this permission error:

> Permission denied on Cloud KMS key. Please ensure that your Cloud Storage service account  has been authorized to use this key.

**update**

```sh
☁  nodejs-gcp [master] ⚡  gcloud kms keys get-iam-policy nodejs-gcp --keyring=test --location=global
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:cloud-storage-admin@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service-16536262744@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter
etag: BwWJ2Pdc5YM=
version: 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `kmsKeyName`, Google Cloud Storage is the entity calling KMS, not your service account. It's a bit confusing:

1. Your service account has permission to call the Cloud Storage API
2. The Cloud Storage service account then calls the KMS API in transit

You will need to [get the Cloud Storage service account](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-service-account) and grant that service account the ability to invoke Cloud KMS:

- Option 1: [Open the API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/storage.projects.serviceAccount.get), authorize, and execute
- Option 2: Install [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install), authenticate to gcloud, install [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l), and run this `curl` command replacing `[PROJECT_ID]` with your project ID:

  ```
  curl -X GET -H "$(oauth2l header cloud-platform)" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/serviceAccount"
  ```
- Option 3: Trust me that it's in the format `service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and get your `[PROJECT_NUMBER]` from [`gcloud projects list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list) or the web interface.

Comment: Sorry, still don't know where is wrong. I am using gcloud sdk and @google_cloud/storage nodejs client library. Update the question, as you can see, I already grant the `roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter` to my cloud storage service account : `cloud-storage-admin@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: `cloud-storage-admin@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` isn't the correct service account. That appears to be a service account in your project. The Cloud Storage service account lives outside your project in `gcs-project.accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. You need to grant the KMS permission to that service account.

Comment: Do you mean I should grant `cloud-storage-admin@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account `cloud KMS admin` permission in GCP - IAM?

Comment: No, you should grant `service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com` the IAM role `roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter`. You can get your project number from `gcloud projects list`.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that anyone who can log into the Cloud Storage browser Web UI then has the ability to encrypt/decrypt with that key? I was hoping to lock the key down to a single service account (the one I created).

Comment: do you mind looking at this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710603/cloud-kms-error-when-attempting-to-use-boot-disk-encryption-key

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to encrypt file using provided service account instead of cloud storage service account? It's a bit confusing. If I login to Cloud Storage then I can see all files decrypted (because Cloud storage service account has permission to decrypt it). If I use my service account then any person who log in to Cloud storage will see encrypted files (of course this person should not have access to KMS key).

I tried to encrypt this file on application side (using KMS) but there is a length limitation (65KB).

Answer (score 0):

Have u added the service account (which should look like "service-xxxxx@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com") to the iam binding, in the members sections?

My terraform code looks like this for the use case:

[image]