# 403 Error on KMS Permissions for Uploading Content to GCP Storage Bucket

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-kms

**Figured it out**

So there's two ways to solve this:

Option 1:

- I was not enabling the project to have access to the KMS Key that was being used to encrypt/decrypt the storage bucket. I was able to test by running the following command in the cli while logged in as myself:

  ```
  gsutil kms authorize -p PROJECTNAME -k projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/global/keyRings/KEYRINGNAME/cryptoKeys/KEYNAME
  ```
- I then logged in as the service account and tried to upload a file. It was successful after doing so.

Option 2:

- After digging around with the cloud console, I found that there was a Storage Service Account that needed access to Encrypt Decrypt. This account is listed under Storage > Settings > Cloud Storage Service Account.
- It appears that GCP delegates the actual work to this account to perform the upload task. So while it has bucket access (obviously, since it's the Storage Service Account), it did not have KMS Access. After adding KMS Encrypt/Decrypt to this SA, it now worked for me automatically without any gsutil intervention.

I also updated the scope of the SA Credentials for upload to have both cloudkms and devstorage.full_control. I'm not sure if that affected anything, though.

---

**Original Question:**

I'm making a workflow that automatically creates service accounts, storage buckets, and KMS Key Rings & Keys automatically for a multi-tenant hosting environment.

I have a Service Account with limited KMS, SA, and Storage permissions that can create other Service Accounts and allow them to be the administrators of their own tenanted items (EG: Create a Service Account for a Tenant, and it's got full control to that Tenant's KMS and Bucket, but not to other Tenant's).

I'm currently running into an issue getting the new Service Account to be able to upload files, however. It's got all the permissions that it needs:

**1. KMS Admin and Encrypt/Decrypt for its KeyRing
2. Storage Bucket Admin**

But, I get the following error when I try to upload something with that Service Account

```
[403] Errors [ 
          Message[Permission denied on Cloud KMS key. 
          Please ensure that your Cloud Storage service
          account has been authorized to use this key. ] 
      Location[ - ] 
      Reason[forbidden] 
      Domain[global]
```

Here's the code I'm using to assign permissions, followed by the code used to access the bucket:

```
class Program
  {
    private static string solutionLocation = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @".." + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ".." + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ".." + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));

static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Deserialize the JSON File for use with other things
JSONCreds jsonCreds =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONCreds>(
File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(solutionLocation, "gcp-general-sa.json")));



Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",
Path.Combine(solutionLocation, "gcp-general-sa.json"));

KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.Create();

StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create();

//Collect Tenant ID for testing purposes
Console.WriteLine("Tenant ID?");
string TID = Console.ReadLine();
if (TID.Length > 23)
{
     TID = TID.Substring(0, 23);
}

//Setting some variables that are used throughout

string keyID = "key-" + TID;
string keyRingName = "ring-" + TID;
string keyLocationID = "global";
string saName = "sa-" + TID;

//Create a Service Account for this agency
var newServiceAccount = CreateServiceAccount(jsonCreds.project_id, saName, saName);


//Create an API Key for this Service Account, and then decode it 
var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault().CreateScoped(IamService.Scope.CloudPlatform);

var service = new IamService(new IamService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
});

var newServiceAccountFullKey = service.Projects.ServiceAccounts.Keys.Create( new CreateServiceAccountKeyRequest(), "projects/-/serviceAccounts/" + newServiceAccount.Email).Execute();

var newServiceAccountKey = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(newServiceAccountFullKey.PrivateKeyData));
Console.WriteLine("Created Service Account Key For: " + newServiceAccountFullKey.Name);


//Create KMS Key Ring for this agency
KeyRing newKeyRing = CreateKeyRing(client, jsonCreds.project_id, keyLocationID, keyRingName);


//Create a KMS Key in that new Key Ring
CryptoKey newKey = CreateCryptoKey(client, jsonCreds.project_id, keyLocationID, newKeyRing.KeyRingName.KeyRingId, keyID);


//Create Bucket with specified Parameters
Bucket bucket = new Bucket
{
    Location = "us-central1",
    Name = TID,
    StorageClass = StorageClasses.Standard,
    Encryption = new Bucket.EncryptionData()
    {
        DefaultKmsKeyName = newKey.Name
    }
};
var newStorageBucket = storageClient.CreateBucket(jsonCreds.project_id, bucket);

//Set permissions for the new Service Account for the new KeyRing and Bucket
AddMemberToKeyRingPolicy(client, jsonCreds.project_id, keyLocationID, newKeyRing.KeyRingName.KeyRingId, "custom_role_with_multiple_permissions", "serviceAccount:" + newServiceAccount.Email);

AddBucketIamMember(newStorageBucket.Name, "roles/storage.admin", "serviceAccount:" + newServiceAccount.Email);


//Testing uploading to the new bucket with the new account
var newSACredential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(newServiceAccountKey.ToString()).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudkms");

var storage = StorageClient.Create(newSACredential);

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("sample_image.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    storage.UploadObject(newStorageBucket.Name, "sample_image_uploaded.png", null, fileStream);
}
```

}

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? It looks like it's a permissions issue, but I have pretty much every single one available for both Storage and KMS assigned to this new Service Account that gets created on the fly.

Full Stack Trace:

```
Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.CheckFinalProgress() in T:\src\github\google-cloud-dotnet\releasebuild\apis\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\StorageClientImpl.UploadObject.cs:204
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.Execute() in T:\src\github\google-cloud-dotnet\releasebuild\apis\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\StorageClientImpl.UploadObject.cs:154
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadObject(Object destination, Stream source, UploadObjectOptions options, IProgress`1 progress) in T:\src\github\google-cloud-dotnet\releasebuild\apis\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\StorageClientImpl.UploadObject.cs:97
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadObject(String bucket, String objectName, String contentType, Stream source, UploadObjectOptions options, IProgress`1 progress) in T:\src\github\google-cloud-dotnet\releasebuild\apis\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1\StorageClientImpl.UploadObject.cs:70
  at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/btruman/Desktop/gcp_scripts/VOCA Onboarding/Program.cs:136
```

Comment: 1) What roles did you assign to the KMS Key (custom_role_with_multiple_permissions)? 2) You are creating a Storage Client with only Cloud KMS scope. No rights to the storage itself. 3) Show your entire code and show where in your code the error message is happening.

Comment: I recommend that you make everything work with the CLI first. Then translate into c#. This will make it easier to get help. I cannot test your issue as I don't have the time to create the pieces you left out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied on Cloud KMS key when using cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320241/permission-denied-on-cloud-kms-key-when-using-cloud-storage)

Comment: Agree with Seth, you need to add the GCS service account to the key -- we only let entities specifically authorized use your key, so you need to OK GCS using it.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry if you got like 15 notifications, I suck at hitting Shift+Enter... 

Here is a screenshot of the permissions (lots of them, too long to list: https://prnt.sc/pr9mbi

I wasn't thinking that it had to do with scope because the error message was telling me that I didn't have access to KMS, which is the scope that I was applying, but I will go back and try adding storage, as well. Good tip!

Also this more or less is the full code, just missing a some variable assignment, but I updated it to include it.

Comment: @TimDierks I have tried adding the SA to the Key only, Key Ring only, and both with the same result.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm onto something. I took your advice and played around with it in gsutil first. I was able to get it to successfully upload after I authorized the project itself to use the KMS Key!

So, I guess that was it - I was neglecting the fact that KMS can be used in all sorts of contexts, and while my service account has access to it, that doesn't mean the resource the project that the resource is in has the ability to use it. 

Many thanks to Tim and John for the tip!

Comment: The solution of adding KMS roles to the project depends on what you added and to what (whom). You might have given the service account access to all KMS keys. Again the devil is in the details. Typically when you add an IAM Member ID to a Project is for for all parts (services/objects/keys) that the role supports.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm continuing testing to make sure that other service accounts can't access the keys for other tenants, but so far it's looking clean. I suppose that since GCP KMS could be used for resources outside of its own project, it was necessarry to enable it for use with its own project first. Looks like I just need to add another line to enable that for new keys automatically, and I'm in business. Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: Update your answer later with any updates/news. This solution will become important for others implementing KMS and Cloud Storage. Here is a link to an article I wrote about KMS and Cloud Storage for Cloud Run that might interest you. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-identity/ There are some tricks in there to experiment with.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHanley, I'll be sure to keep it updated. Currently trying to work out a way to do what I did with gsutil in C#. Hopefully have that figured out soon.

Answer (score 1):

You must create the Cloud KMS key in the same location as the data you intend to encrypt.For further reference please check link [1].

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-managed-keys#prereqs

Comment: Ah, so I can't create a key in "global" and then use it on a bucket in "us-central1"?

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. Putting the keyring and key in us-central1 (same as bucket) did not fix it, and "global" is not a bucket location.

Answer (score 0):

So there's two ways to solve this:

Option 1:

- I was not enabling the project to have access to the KMS Key that was being used to encrypt/decrypt the storage bucket. I was able to test by running the following command in the cli while logged in as myself:

  ```
  gsutil kms authorize -p PROJECTNAME -k projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/global/keyRings/KEYRINGNAME/cryptoKeys/KEYNAME
  ```
- I then logged in as the service account and tried to upload a file. It was successful after doing so.

Option 2:

- After digging around with the cloud console, I found that there was a Storage Service Account that needed access to Encrypt Decrypt. This account is listed under Storage > Settings > Cloud Storage Service Account.
- It appears that GCP delegates the actual work to this account to perform the upload task. So while it has bucket access (obviously, since it's the Storage Service Account), it did not have KMS Access. After adding KMS Encrypt/Decrypt to this SA, it now worked for me automatically without any gsutil intervention.